# Variable passed from HTML Form to Symfony only displays the first character?

Tags: symfony, forms

I have a HTML form on my CakePHP application that passes a variable that is usually over 30 characters long through to my new Symfony2 application. I'm able to pass the variable from the form to Symfony without issue. However, when I echo the variable that's been passed to Symfony the variable only seems to contain just the first character of the 30/40 character sequence.

The variable is usually like this: `T2psbWFGWjNXbTRob3p0VGEwVENheVZvTVRSRFRVUnFLMDVmYVhnaU5ucFJNVWgzZVZSUlRXOXI=`

The HTML form used by CakePHP is like this:

```
<form id="TestForm" method="POST" action="/web/app_dev.php/instructors/passport/" name="input">
<input type="text" value="UkVsS1JtMW1VRFZvT21raU1HVXJVQ3RaTVRSS2JVd3JWRjVxVEdnbVZEUkZiakZsV2pjemNVWTM=" name="value">
<input type="submit" value="Go to the New Database">
</form>
```

The Symfony2 code is like this:

```
public function passportAction(Request $request)
{
    $passport = $this->getRequest()->get("value");

    // Get variables from the search form
    $value = $passport['value'];

    $session = new Session();
    $session->start();

    $session->set('passport', $value);
    $sessionval = $session->get('passport');

    print_r($sessionval);

    return $this->render('DatabaseBundle:Default:test.html.twig', array(
        'pagename' => 'Database Does Not Exist',
        'branchname' => 'Test Branch',
        'group' => '0',
        'something' => $sessionval
    ));
}
```

With this code, and using that variable, in Symfony2 the only thing that is displayed when the variable is echoed is `T`. What is going on?

Comment: Can you try to print/echo `$passport` please?
If this variable is ok I'll explain why you are getting this "bug"

Comment: I've used `print_r($passport)` and the full variable has been displayed.

Comment: Ok, as I thought, I write you the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bug comes from the fact that when you wrote :

```
$passport = $this->getRequest()->get("value");
```

$passport already contains your variable as a string, but a string is nothing more than a pseudo array of characters.
Then, later on your code, you ask for `$passport['value']` and php is not bothered that you use `[]` on a string because it thinks you are trying to access one character from the whole string.
To finish, maybe the trickiest part, where I might be wrong on explaining. You are trying to access to the value pointed by `'value'` key, in fact `'value`' key does not exist but I think a cast is done by php here, and it is resolved as the value `0`.

Answer (score 0):

try this $this->getRequest()->get("TestForm")['value']